# Webscraping Javascript Elements with Requests and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on my very first Python project using BeautifulSoup to webscrape data from https://www.tva.com/Environment/Lake-Levels/South-Holston.  I understand the basics of webscraping and have been following along with YouTube tutorials.  I've ran into problems though when attempting to extract data from the above URL.

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests

   URL = requests.get('https://www.tva.com/Environment/Lake-Levels/South-Holston')
   soup = BeautifulSoup(URL,'lxml')

   main_body = soup.body.div
   print(main_body.prettify())
```

I use the basic code above to parse the page for the main body of the website.  Upon printing out the parsed content and comparing it to the source code on Google Chrome, I notice that certain elements are missing.  The data that I am trying to parse (generators under Generation Releases) is within a table nestled within an HTML class `<div class="tvawidget"...`.  When comparing the parsed data to the source code, it appears the data within the table and the table itself are exchanged with a `function display(data)`.  I hope all of this isn't too confusing, please let me know if I need to clarify.

[Source Code of data I am trying to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43QMt.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have right, the element is populated by Javascript. But you can simulate the Ajax request with `requests` module, for example:

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.tva.com/Environment/Lake-Levels/South-Holston'
rest_api_url = 'https://www.tva.com/RestApi/generation-releases/{lake_name}?format=json'

html_data = requests.get(url).text
lake_name = re.search(r"lakeName\s*=\s*'(.*)'", html_data).group(1)

data = requests.get(rest_api_url.format(lake_name=lake_name)).json()

# pretty print to screen:    
from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
[{'Day': '05/06/2020', 'Generators': '1', 'Time': '1 AM - Midnight EDT'},
 {'Day': '05/07/2020', 'Generators': '1', 'Time': 'Midnight - Midnight EDT'},
 {'Day': '05/08/2020', 'Generators': '1', 'Time': 'Midnight - 1 AM EDT'}]
```

EDIT:

Screenshot with the URL from Firefox Developer Tools:

[image]

Comment: Ah awesome, thanks!  I noticed that the US Energy Information Administration provides an API for the TVA, could that also be another option for parsing the data within the table?

Comment: @WarrenAustin Yes, it seems that the table you see on the webpage is populated from this Rest API - so the information is the same.

Comment: Could you explain where you got the rest_api_url variable from?

Comment: @WarrenAustin I found the URL looking at Network tab in Firefox Developer Tools (Chrome has something similar too). I added screenshot to my answer with the URL.